# What are the helpful cases of Internals Viewer for SQL Server to convince me to use it?

Tags: sql-server, performance, database-design, data-structures, storage

I am in doubt whether I should spend time for installing, studying and using ["Internals Viewer for SQL Server"](http://internalsviewer.codeplex.com/)
What are the most helpful practical uses to convince me to use it for SQL Server perforamnce tuning, troubleshooting or database design?

Comment: +1 because I think it is a good question, and I wonder why a brave anonymous gave it a -1, without any explanation.

Comment: @iDevlop, thanks, they are too many. I do not mind, I would have proposed showing downvotes and upvotes because I have too many posts with a dozen of votes and final score of 0 which is worse than a negative one (it is more like nothing and no iterest to anyone whatsoever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature list is on the link you gave.

- Allocation Map

  - Displays the physical layout of tables and indexes
  - Displays PFS status
  - Overlay pages in the Buffer Pool
- Page Viewer

  - Displays Data pages including forwarding records and sparse columns
  - Displays Index pages
  - Displays allocation pages (IAM, GAM, SGAM, DCM, and BCM pages)
  - Displays pages with SQL Server 2008 row and page compression

If you are interested in these areas then it beats messing around with `DBCC PAGE` in my opinion.

A few examples of why you might want to use it are

- Looking at the number of rows you are getting per data page.
- Looking at the structure of indexes.
- Understanding what happens when rows get updated, deleted, or inserted.

Comment: +1 thanks but, so far, with this info, I prefer staying with "dbcc page", "dbcc ind" from which, I believe, I would get the same info. I am not in intensive (or frequent) poking into internals to use a separate tool for this.